# White bar appears in ie7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I can't, for the life of me, work out why there's a fat white line down the right hand side of my page in ie7. Especially as the background isn't even white. I want to be rid of it.

Here's a link and screenshot.

> *screenshot not yet allowed*

The bar disappears with `#content{display:none}` . I'd appreciate help with a solution that doesn't involve getting rid of everything! Thank you (first question)

Comment: New users can't post pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ieglobal.css` is handing a width of `923px` to your `HTML` tag which is pushing your page to the left. Remove that and it should center properly and remove that white piece that you are seeing (which is also being added by the same CSS sheet as a background, `url(../img/iestrip.png); OVERFLOW-X: hidden`).

Comment: Thank you. Now just waiting for ie7 to die.

Comment: @user1167194 we all feel the same way :(